# Troubleshooting HTML and PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

Long time reader, first time poster. I am a novice PHP enthusiast, and I have a page that I have been working. Right now I have the DB connection working well and my SELECT statement is giving me the info needed. My problems are two fold (maybe more after this post; *set your phasers to cringe*):

1. At one point, I had the INSERT working, but it suddenly stopped and no amount of tweaking seems to bring it back. I have verified that the INSERT statement works in a seperate PHP file without variables.
2. When I did have the INSERT working, every refresh of the page would duplicate the last entry. I have tried tried several ways to clear out the $_POST array, but I think some of my experimenting lead back to problem #1.

```html
<?php 
$dbhost = "REDACTED";
$dbuser = "REDACTED";
$dbpass = "REDACTED";
$dbname = "guest_list";
// Create a database connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Test if connection succeeded
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  die("DB's not here, man: " . 
      mysqli_connect_error() . 
      " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
     );
}
// replacement for mysql_real_escape_string()
function html_escape($html_escape) {
  $html_escape =  htmlspecialchars($html_escape, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
  return $html_escape;
}

// Posting new data into the DB
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $first = html_escape($_POST['first']);
  $last = html_escape($_POST['last']);
  $contact = html_escape($_POST['contact']);
  $associate = html_escape($_POST['associate']);

  $insert = "INSERT INTO g_list (";
  $insert .= "g_fname, g_lname, g_phone, g_association) ";
  $insert .= "VALUES ('{$first}', '{$last}', '{$contact}', '{$associate}')";
  $insert .= "LIMIT 1";
  $i_result = mysqli_query($connection, $insert);
// I have verified that the above works by setting the varialble 
// in the VALUES area to strings and seeing it update
}

$query  = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM g_list ";
$query .= "ORDER BY g_id DESC";
$q_result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Guest List</title>
    <link href="guest.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>REDACTED</h1>
      <h2>Guest Registry</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="registry">
        <form name="formup" id="main_form" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Please enter your name into the registry</legend>
            <p class="first">First Name: 
              <input type="text" name="first" value="" placeholder="One or more first names" size="64"></p>
            <p class="last">Last Name:
              <input type="text" name="last" value="" placeholder="Last name" size="64"></p>
            <p class="contact">Phone Number or Email:
              <input type="text" name="contact" value="" placeholder="" size="32"></p>
            <p class="associate">Your relation?
              <input type="text" name="associate" value="" placeholder="" size="128"></p>
            <p class="submit">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" title="add" value="submit" placeholder=""></p>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3>Guest List:</h3>            
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname(s)</th><th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Phone or Email</th><th>Association</th>
      </tr>

      <?php while($guest = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q_result)) {
  echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $guest["g_fname"] . "</td>"
    . "<td>" . $guest["g_lname"] . "</td>"
    . "<td>" . $guest["g_phone"] . "</td>"
    . "<td>" . $guest["g_association"] . "</td>" . "</tr>";
} ?>

    </table>
    <footer>
      <div>Copyright <?php echo date("Y"); ?>, REDACTED, LLC.</div>

      <?php
if (isset($connection)) {
  mysqli_close($connection);
}
      ?>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not doing any error checking on your queries, you just assume they'll work. Check your error logs.

Comment: you can check your insert query for error like this `$i_result = mysqli_query($connection, $insert) or trigger_error($connection->error."[$insert]");`

Answer (score 3):

These two lines will fail:

```
$insert .= "VALUES ('{$first}', '{$last}', '{$contact}', '{$associate}')";
$insert .= "LIMIT 1";
```

Two problems here, all with the second line:

- No SPACE between ) and LIMIT: **)LIMIT 1** is your code;
- LIMIT 1 in an INSERT is not allowed....

Comment: Anyone have ideas on how to prevent the browser from resending the data for form entry?  I have tried adding 

    unset($_POST); 
    $_POST = array(); 

to the bottom of the if statement to no avail.

Comment: You can not reset a POST since the browser will just generate it again. I would use a separate php script for processing the form (so just split your page in two scripts and use a window.location to load the form after the form has been processed).